# Transform quoted elixir code to a code string

Tags: metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree, elixir

I have a situation where I am expecting some quoted elixir code to be an atom. If the wrong quoted code is passed in I want to raise an error and show what the wrong code was.

Simplest way to show what I need is with an example.

```
quoted_code = quote do: %{}
"%{}" = some_func(quoted_code)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with `Macro.to_string/2`

```
Macro.to_string(quote do: %{}) #=> "%{}"
```

Comment: ok I am positive I tried that. Must have missed out a bracket round the quote or something.